# scala combine collections as 1d collections

Tags: r, scala, collections

I'd like to get functions like R language's `c` function :

```
#R
print(c(c(1,2,3),2,3,c(1,2)))
> c(1,2,3,2,3,1,2)
```

my solution is

```
trait SeqMagnet[A] {
  type Result = Seq[A]

  def apply(): Result
}

object SeqMagnet {

  implicit class fromString(x: String) extends SeqMagnet[String] {
    override type Result = Seq[String]

    override def apply(): Result = Seq(x)
  }

  implicit class fromInt(x: Int) extends SeqMagnet[Int] {
    override type Result = Seq[Int]

    override def apply(): Result = Seq(x)
  }

  implicit class fromDouble(x: Double) extends SeqMagnet[Double] {
    override type Result = Seq[Double]

    override def apply(): Result = Seq(x)
  }

  implicit class fromSeq(x: TraversableOnce[_]) extends SeqMagnet[_] {
    override type Result = Seq[_]

    override def apply(): Result = x.toSeq
  }

}


object Combine {
  def toSeq(magnet: SeqMagnet[_]) = magnet()

  def c(any: SeqMagnet[_]*) = {
    any.map(toSeq(_)).flatten
  }
}
```

but I get `seq[Any]`  from this function,
and some error for `fromSeq` CLASS

**my expected is like this**

```
# pseudo-code
def c[A](A( or A collections)*):Seq[A] 
----
input: Int Seq(1,2,3) ,seq(4,5)
output: Seq(1,2,3,4,5):Seq[Int]
----
input: String Seq("a",b"), "d",seq("c","e")
output: Seq("a","b","d","c","e")
```

my scala version is 2.11

Comment: Use a type parameter instead of an existential type. You would also need to combine this with the **magnet** pattern to be able to accepts both sequences as well as plain values. - In general, I would recommend you to avoid needing this.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez   I used to use R language,`c` is easy to use. my business code used` "col1":+Seq("col2","col3")++Seq("col4",col5")` very frequently,  that's why i want to implement this function. why you recommend me to avoid this.  thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a **type parameter**, like the one you show in your pseudo code.

```scala
import scala.language.implicitConversions

object c {
  private trait CMagnet[+A] {
    def get: Seq[A]
  }
  
  private object CMagnet {
    implicit def fromPlainValue[A](a: A): CMagnet[A] = new CMagnet[A] {
      def get: Seq[A] = a :: Nil
    }
    
    implicit def fromSeq[A](seq: Seq[A]): CMagnet[A] = new CMagnet[A] {
      def get: Seq[A] = seq
    }
  }
  
  def apply[A](args: CMagnet[A]*): Seq[A] =
    args.flatMap(_.get)
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```scala
val seq = Seq("A", "B")
val result = c(seq, "C", "D", Seq("E", "F", "G"), "H")
// result: Seq[String] = ArraySeq(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H)
```

Or like this:

```scala
val seq = c("A", "B")
val result = c(seq, "C", "D", c("E", c("F", "G")), "H")
// result: Seq[String] = ArraySeq(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H)
```

The reason I said it would be better to avoid this is that it needs a lot of *(advanced)* code to something which one may think is not that useful, but if you need it there you go.

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/5136Mw6CT9WUx2kBktddOA/4)*.

Comment: Perhaps Shapeless would make this safer than implicit conversions, but yeah, it'd still be way too complicated.

Comment: @user the good thing about the **magnet** is that it is way safer than implicit conversions in general. Since the conversion will only happen where the magnet is expected.

Comment: I guess so, yeah. I've had some bad experience with `implicit def` lately, so it makes me a bit uneasy when I see it :)

Comment: @user yeah I also do not like them and I would certainly prefer them to not exist in general, but the **magnet** is a good **last resort** solution for some problems.

Comment: my scala 2.11 version, your code  must use `private [c] trait ` and ` private [c] object `,or remove private declare

Comment: @SummersKing Uhm, I just tried with `2.11.12` on the **Scastie** and it worked without problems. Which exact version do you have? Or maybe you put those inside another thing like a package object?

Comment: my scala version is 2.11.12 too, and not package object, I worked with scala, when I paste your code on my `idea(2019..3.4)`, private object CMgnet is grey(Declaration is never used)`. and compiled well, but when I use this object, it prints `java. lang.nosuchMethodError`, my project also have some java code , used java8.never mind i have solve this use `private[c]`